# Error while updating via terminal from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates, cache

I get this error multiple times (and these codes underneath still run for some reason)

```
This likely means that your installation is broken.

Try running the command:  

gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache

to make things work again for the time being.

Processing triggers for menu ...
dpkg: libreoffice-core: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
```